# React Redux container component

Tags: reactjs, redux, components

I am writing a simple React + Redux Container Component.  Given below is the code

```
export default class LoginContainerComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        connect( this.mapStateToProps, this.mapDispatchToProps )( LoginComponent )
    }

    render() {
        return (<LoginComponent></LoginComponent>);
    }

    mapStateToProps( state ) {
        return {
            loginText: 'Login'
            ,
            registerText: 'Register'
        }
    }

    mapDispatchToProps( dispatch ) {
        return {
            onLoginClick: () => {
                alert( 'login clicked' );
            },
            onRegisterClick: () => {
                alert( 'register clicked' );
            }
        }
    };
 }
```

I have a few questions surrounding this
1. Is this overall approach correct, specifically where I define the connect( in the constructor?  A lot of the examples I have seen define connect outside the component, but if I define this outside the component then I do not have access to mapStateToPrope, and mapDispatchToProps which I think should be inside the component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connect function is a [high order component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) (HOC) and doesn't need to be a defined as a class itself. The redux document has some [examples](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#implementing-container-components) of how to do this. They are using ES6 syntax which you may not, so the below is equivalent for you.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        loginText: 'Login'
        ,
        registerText: 'Register'
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        onLoginClick: () => {
            alert('login clicked');
        },
        onRegisterClick: () => {
            alert('register clicked');
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginComponent)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
class LoginContainerComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        //you actually dont need this atm
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (<LoginComponent></LoginComponent>);
    }
 }

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    loginText: 'Login',
    registerText: 'Register'
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onLoginClick: () => alert('login clicked'),
    onRegisterClick: () => alert('register clicked')
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )(LoginComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to have your component and a separate container. It's called Presentational and Container components, you can read more in this [Medium post by the creator of Redux](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.ivzwdm2sc). But basically the idea is that you keep your `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` outside of your component, which will receive everything it needs as a prop.